# Comportamento inesperado na geração @OneToMany unidirecional (colunas de FK adicionais sendo criadas)

Tags: jpa, eclipse-link

Abaixo segue as duas entidades com os relacionamentos de forma unidirecional:

**CustomerService.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_service")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "tenant_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty = PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
public class CustomerService implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_customer_service")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "tenant_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name = "date_service")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "average_budget")
    private BigDecimal averageBudget;

    @Column(name = "service_situation")
    private boolean situation;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_customerService")
    private Set<ServiceItem> serviceItem;

    //Getter and Setter...
}
```

**Destination.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="destination")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT) 
public class Destination implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination")
    private Long idDestination;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_destination")
    @Valid
    private Set<Image> images;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_destination")
    private Set<ServiceItem> serviceItem;

    //Geter and Setter...
}
```

**ServiItem.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "service_item")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name = "tenant_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty = PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class ServiceItem implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_service_item")
    private Long id;


    private Destination destination;


    private CustomerService customerService;

    //Getter and Setter
    }
```

Bem, a geração das tabelas no BD é feito pelo eclipselink, mas o mesmo está criando (além das colunas **fk_customerService** e **fk_destination**), mais duas colunas como FK! 
Abaixo segue uma imagem para ilustrar o problema:
[image: imagem]

Como posso arrumar essa geração?

Comment: O relacionamento não é unidirecinal, já que você tem os atributos `Destination` e `CustomerService` em `ServiceItem`. Isso me parece um bug, mas de qualquer forma acho que vale a pena tentar definir as anotações `@JoinColumn` na classe `ServiceItem` ao invés das outras.

Comment: @utluiz, irei arrumar. Falta de atenção a minha. Mas se eu definir as anotações de `@JoinColumn` na `ServiceItem` não irá tornar o relacionamento bi-direcional?

Comment: Sim, mas é só um teste para ver se resolve o problema da duplicação de FK. Outro teste seria remover temporariamente esses atributos para ver se o EclipseLink está considerando eles mesmo sem as anotações.

Comment: Legal @utluiz. Vou realizar os testes!